# Java GUI Библиотеки

Tags: java, gui, поиск-библиотек

А есть какие-то сторонние GUI библиотеки для Java?

Comment: Они там все сторонние...

Comment: ещё можно брать сразу Android в качестве GUI

Answer (score 1):

Сразу
[вот](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=GUI%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20Java&oq=GUI%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20Java&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

или
[вот](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=GUI%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20Java&oq=GUI%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20Java&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=GUI%20library%20for%20Java)

вообще есть стандартная Swing. Если в ней хорошо разобраться, то довольно интересная и легкая в применении.

Comment: Про Swing пишут что он медленно работает

Comment: тогда могу сказать, что вопрос  поставлен не совсем корректно

Comment: откровенно java  не предназначена для gui

Comment: @zloj, расскажите это гуглу https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java

Comment: Oceinicчто именно Вас интересует?

Comment: первый вопрос задан оJava GUI Библиотеки, потом вы мне даете ссылку на androidю Что именно интересует? Определитесь с вопросом и задайте его правильно.

Comment: 1. Вопрос не мой. 2. GUI Android'a написано на Java. 3. Если в Google посчитали, что Java подходит для GUI, значит, скорее всего, так оно и есть